# AJAX call not firing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In the below code from my .js file, the first function `save_audition` is working great. The second one, which I just copy/pasted and changed some variables is not,f or some reason. I've done some troubleshooting and ruled out my .php file (which works fine when called manually) as well as the .html and determined that this script just isn't firing for some reason.

This is my first ever project using AJAX, so it could be something very simple, not sure. FYI, I'm working within Wordpress's AJAX framework using admin-ajax.php

EDIT: Here is a pastebin to the main plugin file: http://pastebin.com/AaJ6QqTx

Here is the code from the .js file. The first on('click') event (save_audition) is working fine, the 2nd (hide_audition) is working in the sense the `return false;` works to prevent the link from firing, but the actual AJAX click event isn't happening.

```
//Save (or remove) an audition from the user's saved auditions meta using ajax
   $('.save-audition').on('click', function() {
      var post_id = $(this).attr('data-post_id');
      var nonce = $(this).attr('data-nonce');
      var clicked = $(this);


      $.ajax({
         type : 'post',
         dataType : 'json',
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl, //we can use this value because in our php file we used wp_localize_script
         data : {action: 'tps_save_audition', post_id : post_id, nonce: nonce},
         success: function(response) {
                $('#alerts').append('<div class="alert"><div class="alert-icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></div><div class="alert-message">'+response.message+'</div><div class="close"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div></div>');
                $('#alerts .alert').fadeIn(400);


            if(response.type == 'success') {
                clicked.children('span').children('.fa-stack-2x').addClass('fa-check');
                clicked.children('span').children('.fa-stack-1x').addClass('saved');
            } else if (response.type = 'removed') {
                clicked.children('span').children('.fa-stack-2x').removeClass('fa-check');
                clicked.children('span').children('.fa-stack-1x').removeClass('saved');
            } else {
               alert(response.message);
            }
         }
      })   
    return false;
   });

   //Hide an audition from the user's view by saving it as user_meta
   $('.hide-audition').on('click', function() {
      var post_id = $(this).attr('data-post_id');
      var nonce = $(this).attr('data-nonce');
      var clicked = $(this);


      $.ajax({
         type : 'post',
         dataType : 'json',
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl, //we can use this value because in our php file we used wp_localize_script
         data : {action: 'tps_hide_audition', post_id : post_id, nonce: nonce},
         success: function(response) {
                $('#alerts').append('<div class="alert"><div class="alert-icon"><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></div><div class="alert-message">'+response.message+'</div><div class="close"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div></div>');
                $('#alerts .alert').fadeIn(400);


            if(response.type == 'success') {
                clicked.children('i').css('color', 'red');
            } else {
               alert(response.message);
            }
         }
      })   
    return false;
   });
```

Comment: I'll bet a nickle that $(this) actually isn't the 'this' you think it is. Open the dev console and see what 'this', it's very easy for 'this' to be in a scope you didn't anticipate, which is why you see a lot var that = this; outside of closures and callbacks. There is some proper jquery way of binding the scope I just can't recall it off the top of my head.

Comment: Hmm, after some Googling I suspect you're right. I did set a variable to $(this) outside of the AJAX call which is the solution suggested in a lot of threads, but there must be something else. I'll keep searching. Thanks for the tip. Maybe I'll PayPal you a nickle ;)

Comment: i think the php code isn't relevant here, try posting the resulting html. To see if some php variables mess with html attributes

Comment: I removed the php/html and added a link to a pastebin with the only other code I'm using (there are just 3 files) which is the main file from the plugin I've wrapped this in. Is that what you mean?

Comment: "*is not working at all*" What does that mean? What's not working? You getting JavaScript errors? The AJAX doesn't fire at all? The AJAX *does* fire, but you're not receiving any `success` data back?

Comment: Sorry, to be more specific: It is not firing at all but there are no js errors. If I remove the Ajax part and let the link fire normally, the database is updated and the page is redirected back, so the functionality is working, the AJAX just isn't firing when the element is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

OK well, as usual it comes down to a stupid coder error. In my html I had TWO elements with the class "hide-audition" by accident and that was breaking it.

I guess I'll leave this question up for others as a reminder to comb through every piece of code carefully while troubleshooting.